Azure Devops - Changing test configuration has resulted in losing test execution history in the test report
I changed the configuration of a test suite and now the tests are showing as active. I can see the test execution history on the test cases, but the previous test results are not shown in the test report.
I've change the configuration back to what it was originally and the test cases remain as Active and still cant see the results in test report.
How do I go about getting the test report to show the previous test history?

I can reproduce the issue on my side. The cause of this issue seems to be that the tester becomes Unassigned after changing the configuration, but the tester filter of the Progress report does not have the Unassigned option.
In the execution history, tester filter has Unassigned option, so the old history is visible.

In the progress report, tester filter doesn't have Unassigned option.

As a workaround, you can check the history from execution history. It seems like a bug, you can report it to the Azure DevOps support from Developer Community.
